# Deferred execution linq c# Tolower toupper tostring

Tags: c#, deferred-execution

Im wondering when I do this:

```
IQueryable<customer> customers = new IQueryable<customer>();
var customers = db.customers.Where(x=> x.Name.ToLower() == "john");
```

Does the deferred execution stop at the use of methods like "ToLower() or ToUpper or Tostring"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the deferred execution stop at the use of methods like "ToLower() or ToUpper or Tostring"?

It does not matter which method is called the line `x.Name.ToLower() == "john"` will not be executed (actually the complete `Where()` will not be called) unless the `customers` variable is materialized or enumerated or unless you bring the results in memory by calling `ToList()` at the end of the query.